# custom HTML list of values from DB using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to make a list of topics (title, date, author etc) in really easy way, something like this:

```
    <a href="#">New Idea</a><label>date</label><br/>
    <label>author</label>
    <hr/>
```

But with own data from database. So every time before the page is loaded, it checks how many topics there are in the database and according to this number it will generate the snippet of code like above, with data from the database.
I want to make it, that I loop this snippet of code so many times as there are topics in the database and generate this code via the `echo` command in PHP. But I think it is not the best solution, so that's why I want to ask you.

Thanks

Comment: Do you know how to use loops in PHP, or the MySQLi extension? Do you know any MySQL? Also, it shows a significant lack of effort and courtesy to not bother typing words out in full ("smth", etc).

Comment: Nice start. `I want to make a list` and after `<a>` LOL.... Why you don't make a list? `<ul>/<ol>`

Comment: You say you want to fetch entries from some db of yours. So where is your code doing that?

Comment: put some effort in it, it's not a problem we can solve it's not even a problem to begin with...

Comment: When I wrote list I meant it abstract (some kind of list, no html list). And I have no code, because I wrote here my idea how to do that and I told that I think it's a not good way so wanna help from you. If I want some custom html code to repeat for n time with value from DB, so what's the best way I an do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways of doing it: one, first retrieving all the data from the db and then echoing. And what you say, echoing while retrieving the data at the same time. if one method is better than the other is just depending on you situation.

Usually i work as you say: each snippet is independent (like an ajax call or like an API call) hence each one queries the database and echoes output on its own.

P.S.: You could improve your wording .... it's complicated to understand your post.